# JavaScript: Using a function parameter to retrieve a javascript object key

Tags: javascript, object

Is there a reason this is 'undefined, and is there a way to avoid it?

I am trying to dynamically retrieve the desired error message from my error messages object. This is a very simplified version of it.

```
var language = {
    errorMsg: {
        helloWorld: "hello world"
    }
};

function displayErrorMsg(msg) {
    console.log(msg); // output: helloWorld
    console.log(language.errorMsg.helloWorld); // output: hello world
    console.log(language.errorMsg[msg]); // output: Uncaught ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined 
}

displayErrorMsg('helloWorld');
```

Comment: This code works (after your edit). http://jsfiddle.net/cx7YV/

Answer (score 2):

Well in your example `language.errorMsgTSD` does not exist

You could do:

```
function displayErrorMsg(msg) {
    console.log(language.errorMsg[msg]); // output: hello world
}
```

Answer (score 1):

errorMsgTSD isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because `language` does not have a `errorMsgTSD` field. You need to create it like this:

```
var language = {
    errorMsg: {
        helloWorld: "hello world"
    },
    errorMsgTSD: {
        helloWorld: "hello world"
    },
};
```

Or perhaps you need to change your function to be:

```
function displayErrorMsg(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(language.errorMsg[msg]);
}
```